# How to fix google sheet shortcuts in ubuntu?

Tags: google

I want to active google sheet shortcuts in ubuntu. When I was trying to alt+H, it directly jumped to help.
How can I use it?

Comment: This may be more a feature of Google's Chrome webbrowser, and Firefox.  When I use alt-H in Chrome, I am prompted to enable the shortcuts.

Comment: What are you expecting Alt+H to do?  If you are using Google Sheets in Firefox Alt+H brings up the Firefox help menu.  If you are using Google Sheets in Chrome Alt+H brings up the Google Sheets help.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using a Google Sheet opened in Firefox (which I use daily), if you click on Help you will see the following menu

[image]

from which you will see that to access Keyboard shortcuts the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> which in turn presents:

[image]

Indeed, if you have opened Google Sheets in Firefox, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> will bring up Firefox help menu.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> will invoke Find and Replace in Sheets.